# Search bar results not showing in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

i've created a Search method which search through the content of the tableview. This works fine and every time i write in the search bar it adds the object to an array called filteredArray and shows the number of tableviewcells that are equal to filteredArray.count. i've tested this with NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);

The problem is i want to show the filteredArray in the tableview when u search. i've changed the cellForRowAtIndexPath method for this, but it just gives me empty tableviewcells. What am i doing wrong?

Not searching:

[image]

searching "ru":

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    LanguageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[LanguageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

        if (tableView == self.tableViewData) {
    cell.patternLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0]];


        } else{
            cell.patternLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        }
    return cell;
}
```

search methods:

```
-(void) searchThroughdata {

    self.filteredArray = nil;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [c] %@",self.searchBar.text];


    self.filteredArray = [[finalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);



}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self searchThroughdata];
}
```

Comment: Show your search delegate methods code.

Comment: done. i've added the methods and 2 pictures that illustrate when i'm not searching and when i'm searching.

Comment: `LanguageCell` - is the cell registered with the table? When is `cell = [[LanguageCell alloc] initWithStyle:...` being run?

Comment: its registered in a UITableViewCell class called. languageCell.h and .m

Comment: That is not what registered means (that is defined). Debug and tell me when `cell = [[LanguageCell alloc] initWithStyle:...` is run.

Comment: when the cell does not exist.

i've tried checking when its running. it seem to run kind of randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 table views, the cell is registered with one but not the other - this is the way prototype cells work when you define them in a storyboard which I guess you have done.

When the search table view doesn't get a dequeued cell you create one with `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` but this doesn't create your `patternLabel`. So, you don't get a crash, because you return a cell, but the cell is empty because the label doesn't exist.

Your best options:

1. Remove the prototype cell, create an XIB and register the NIB with each table view explicitly
2. Not to use a search controller (so you only have 1 table view, manage the search bar yourself)

Answer (score 1):

you can make [yourTableView reloadData] after you add a new character